# Lua only call a function if it exists?

Tags: function, lua

I would like to call a function in a Lua file but only if the function exists,
How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
if foo ~= nil then foo() end
```

Comment: If you want to load the file only if `foo` is defined there, then this is much harder, if not impossible.

Comment: In that case foo might be a string, number or table, too.
Would be better to test    if type(foo) == 'function' then foo() end

Comment: didn't thought about that, you are right. So the right condition is a way more difficult, isn't it?
    if type(foo)=='function' or 
    (type(foo)=='table' and getmetatable(foo).__call ~= nil) then 
        foo()
    end
btw: how to format code fragments in comments?

Comment: @Maze, there's also userdata to handle. If you allow the debug library, then all types can have `__call` metamethod. I think the simplest solution is the best.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most robust that covers all possibilities (the object doesn't exist, or it exists but is not a function, or is not a function but is callable), is to use a protected call to actually call it: if it doesn't exist then nothing really gets called, if it exists and is callable the result is returned, otherwise nothing really gets called.

```
function callIfCallable(f)
    return function(...)
        error, result = pcall(f, ...)
        if error then -- f exists and is callable
            print('ok')
            return result
        end
        -- nothing to do, as though not called, or print('error', result)
    end
end

function f(a,b) return a+b end
f = callIfCallable(f)
print(f(1, 2)) -- prints 3
g = callIfCallable(g)
print(g(1, 2)) -- prints nothing because doesn't "really" call it
```

Answer (score 2):

A non instantiated variable is interpreted as `nil` so below is another possibility.

```
if not foo then
    foo()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string that may be a name of a global function:

```
local func = "print"

if _G[func] then 
    _G[func]("Test") -- same as: print("test")
end
```

and If you have a function that might be valid:

```
local func = print

if func then
    func("ABC") -- same as: print("ABC")
end
```

If you're wondering what happens and what's the background on above, `_G` Is a global table on lua that stores every global function in it. This table stores global variables by name as key, and the value (function, number, string). If your `_G` table doesn't contain the name of object you're looking for, Then your object may not be existing or it's a local object.

On the second code box, We're creating a `local` variable named `func` and giving it the `print` function as value. (Take a note that there's no need to parenthesis. If you open parenthesis, It calls the function and gets the output value, not the function it self).

the `if` statement on the block, checks whether your function exists or not. In lua script, not only `booleans` can be checked using a simple `if` statement, but functions and existence of objects can be checked using a simple `if` statement.

Inside our `if` block we're calling our `local` variable, just like how we call the global function of the value (`print`), It's more like giving our function (`print`) a second name or a shortcut name for easy using.